# Understanding MySQL Deadlocks

Tags: mysql, deadlock

Two database sessions are deadlocking and, based on all I have read, the second session is not supposed to be locking anything at that point.  Here's the scenario.

MySQL 5.7
Isolation Level: Repeatable Read

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
   id INT NOT NULL,
   col2 CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(id),
   UNIQUE KEY test_uk1 (col2)
 );
```

1. Open two sessions to the database
2. First session:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'OLD');
```

3. Second session:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'OLD');
```

the session is waiting on lock

4. First session:

```sql
UPDATE test SET col2 = 'NEW' WHERE id = 1;
```

The Second session gets:
   *insert into test values (2, 'OLD') Error Code: 1213. Deadlock found when trying to get lock …*

I believe the second session has to fail with *"Duplicate Key .."* error.  And if I try to drop the table from the first session, I cannot until I issue *rollback* from the second session.
Please help me understand what on earth the second session locks.
Here's the *show engine innodb status* output:

```sql
******************** 1. row *********************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name: 
Status: 
=====================================
2019-08-16 15:42:44 0x70000db0a000 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 57 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 443 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 703922 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 704345
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 337
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 370
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 1741, OS waits 332
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 484, OS waits 0
RW-sx spins 10, rounds 26, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 1741.00 RW-shared, 484.00 RW-excl, 2.60 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-08-16 15:40:30 0x70000dbd6000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 7976, ACTIVE 5 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 14, OS thread handle 123145531990016, query id 11920 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
insert into test values (2, 'OLD')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 139 page no 4 n bits 72 index test_uk1 of table `pi_admin`.`test` trx id 7976 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 4f4c442020202020; asc OLD     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 7975, ACTIVE 11 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 12, OS thread handle 123145532825600, query id 11922 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
UPDATE test
    SET col2 = 'NEW'
  WHERE id = 1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 139 page no 4 n bits 72 index test_uk1 of table `pi_admin`.`test` trx id 7975 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 4f4c442020202020; asc OLD     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 139 page no 4 n bits 72 index test_uk1 of table `pi_admin`.`test` trx id 7975 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 4f4c442020202020; asc OLD     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 7981
Purge done for trx's n:o < 7981 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 29
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 281479689064904, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 281479689064000, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 281479689062192, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 7975, ACTIVE 145 sec
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 12, OS thread handle 123145532825600, query id 11922 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
--------
FILE I/O
--------
...
```

Comment: What client are you using to connect AND is it configured to **NOT** autocommit ?

Comment: I tried this from Workbench and command line mysql client.  Got the same behavior.  I did make sure the autocommit was set to 0.